# Hide custom button on visualforce page

Tags: apex, controller, commandbutton

I have a requirement to hide custom button when condition is satisfied.On case I have person_role field.If the field is null then I need to hide custom button on vf page.

`<apex:commandButton value="Confirm" action="{!Confirm}" />`

```
if(case.Person_Role__c==NULL){
          ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'order cannot be created'));
```

Any help

Comment: there are plenty of questions that have an answer related to conditional rendering in visual force pages

Comment: Use `rendered` attribute.

Comment: do we need to declare anything in the controller part..

Comment: Yes, you need to have boolean property, and use that boolean property in the `rendered` attribute. The link posted in the other comments should give you a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rendered` attribute in `apex:commandButton` like below:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Confirm" action="{!Confirm}"  rendered="{!ishide}"/>
```

Modified the class like below by using an extra boolean variable (**ishide**):

```
if(case.Person_Role__c==NULL){
 ishide = false;
         ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'order cannot be created'));
}
```

make sure you declare the **ishide** with `{get;set;}` and in constructor intialize the variable as `ishide=true`

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple just do the following steps:

1. create one boolean variable say `hidebtn` and make the value false
2. Make it true in the below code:

   ```
   if(case.Person_Role__c==NULL){
       hidebtn = true;
       ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'order cannot be created'));
   }
   ```

Put the variable in button rendered condition.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Confirm" action="{!Confirm}" rendered={!NOT(hidebtn)}/>
```

It will solve your purpose.

Comment: then accept the ans so other can find it useful.